# How do I bypass this removal denial?

Tags: linux, ssh

Pardon the ignorance and if this is a repeat question.
Don't quite understand SSH keys, but I need to understand SSH keys so here I am lol..
Previous posted about having issues with an SSH transfer.
So I'm trying to remove the SSH keys from my machine.
Started here:

```
/bin/rm -v /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*
/bin/rm: remove write-protected regular file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key'? yes
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key': Permission denied
/bin/rm: remove write-protected regular file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub'? yes
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub': Permission denied
/bin/rm: remove write-protected regular file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key'? yes
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key': Permission denied
/bin/rm: remove write-protected regular file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub'? yes
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub': Permission denied
/bin/rm: remove write-protected regular file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key'? yes
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key': Permission denied
/bin/rm: remove write-protected regular file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub'? yes
/bin/rm: cannot remove '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub': Permission denied
```

So then I was like, well bugga that didn't work. How do I remove any and all ssh keys from my machine?

What other method could I use, or what can I do to get this one to work?
Any guidance would be appreciated. I'm out of my element on this one so, Barney style response preferred. Thanks!

Ramhound - change permissions on keys? I do not even know how.
Currently running `Ubuntu for Windows`
Version: 20.04? Whatever the latest is

Comment: Did you run this `/bin/rm -v /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*` as a regular user? A regular user cannot modify anything in `/etc/`. If you really want to remove these files, act as root. Removing regular files and removing keys from an authentication agent are two different things. Your problem has nothing to do with the agent.

Comment: Question absolutely is inappropriate on SO amd belongs here (but its still difficult to understand)

Comment: Have you changed the permissions on the key? What are the permissions on those keys exactly? [Edit] your question to include this vital information.

Comment: Davidgo - this wasn't the question. Was feelin some type of way, I'll remove that bit when I got back to edit with Ramhound's questions.

Comment: Kamil - Thought I was. Guess it woulda worked if I had, I'll go run it again and come back.